# Azure WebJob not running as per schedule

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have an issue where an Azure WebJob I created (on a Web App) is not running using the cronjob Trigger I specified. I am able to click on the WebJob, then click Run and it does run fine with no errors. A screenshot of the WebJobs in the portal is shown below.

[image: WebJobs List]
As you can see, the Trigger is set to run at 9:30 AM every day, but it is never run automatically as per the trigger, only manually using Run. The WebJob itself is set to run a .exe which is contained inside a .zip.

Here are the settings I used when creating the WebJob.
[image: Creating new WebJob]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to make sure you have Always On enabled in your App, which requires it to run in Basic or higher mode.

See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduledCRON for details.

Comment: I have a job scheduler on a Basic:Small and it is not triggering. I see it in the webjob (as the screen shot of the question).

Comment: Do you have Always On enabled?

Comment: Actually I found out the issue. The always on was on (of course). The problem came from the fact that I was deploying using msbuild and that the settings.job file schedule CRON had an error (I forgot the 6th parameter). You don't get any errors. It just doesn't start automatically.

Comment: I see. Yes ideally it should show a warning or error.

Comment: The funny thing is that the Portal is showing the CRON expression even if there's an error ;). (Just saying)

Answer (score 4):

Faced the similar issue.With reference to the below link

https://raskarovblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/16/why-is-my-azure-webjob-cron-expression-is-not-working/

Azure team states that Azure WebJob CRON uses NCronTab with six parameters (five and seven parameters are not accepted).

If you look at NCronTab Docs, you will notice that they use 5 parameters. Azure team explains that they also pass “Seconds” parameter which is not used by default by NCronTab.

Cron format below

{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day of the week}

To run the webjobs every day at 9.30 am will be

```
{"schedule":"0 30 9 * * *"}
```

And also check the time scheduled in the azure webjobs and your local time.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments of David Ebbo's answer, the webjob won't be triggered automatically if your CRON expression is not correct.

In this [piece of relevant MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs#CreateScheduledCRON), the following CRON expression is mentioned and does not work:

```
{
"schedule": "0 */15 * * * *"
}
```

Instead, use this:

```
{
"schedule": "0 0/15 * * * *"
}
```

This way I got my webjob running every 15 minutes.

Comment: "always on" is ON, tried both, neither works

Answer (score 0):

Just putting this here for the googlers.

Remember Azure is running on UTC time so 9:30 in your timezone might be different in Azure time.

I'm PST so if I want to run something at 9:30 I set my CRON expression to 16:30. This becomes a problem with daylight savings time if you need your job to execute at exactly 9:30, you will need to change the CRON expression because UTC does not change with DST.

Comment: Hey there welcome to Stack Overflow! We have guidelines which help keep the content on the site high quality, and in order to best contribute and help others I would recommend checking out some of those guidelines. Specifically, this answer doesn't attempt to answer the question asked, and would be more beneficial as a comment. Googlers who land on the question would likely see your comment on the question before an off topic answer which is unlikely to get  upvoted https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer